# Local testing: make a second DocumentRoot in XP?

Tags: windows, testing, vhosts, hosts

I'm trying to give my computer the priority on a domain name that isn't being broadcast: www.mythiddomain.com.  I set up my vhosts file, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mythirddomain.com
DocumentRoot "C:/www"
<Directory "C:/www">
Options +Indexes FollowSymlinks +ExecCGI
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried editing my hosts file in multiple ways, including `127.0.0.1 mythirddomain.com` and `198.168.1.2 mythirddomain.com`, but I was just jabbing blind.  I'm not sure what the next step is, after changing the vhosts file.

Action:
Browse to mythirddomain.com.

Expected result:
Get my index.php file.

Actual result:
Get inuit.com (they own mythirddomain.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the following file:

```
%SystemRoom%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Add a line like this:

127.0.0.1    mythirddomain.com

This will obviously only have any effect on the local machine.

Comment: Reading below is important, if you want to see how I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1 mythirddomain.com`was correct.  The reason my browser wasn't resolving mythirddomain.com correctly is because I hadn't restarted my browser.